# how to do something at specific time for everyday in android

Tags: java, android

i want to check some url at 9:00 a.m everyday.But how can i do this? I did check some topic and article about AlarmManager and IntentService but i can't get together for my application , is there any example code or something ?Thank you..

Comment: what is your problem with AlarmManager?

Comment: AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Zamanlayici.class);
        intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        //After after 5 seconds
        
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 10, pi); like this code, i can do this specific time between but i can't do this specific time

Comment: So, create a `Calendar` object that is your specific time for the first event, and use a period of `INTERVAL_DAY` to have it recur every 24 hours.

Comment: What is your calendar object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 /Create alarm manager

 AlarmManager mAlarmManger = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

 //Create pending intent & register it to your alarm notifier class
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver_maandag_1e.class);
 intent.putExtra("uur", "1e"); // if you want
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

 //set timer you want alarm to work (here I have set it to 9.00)
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
 calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
 calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

 //set that timer as a RTC Wakeup to alarm manager object
 mAlarmManger .set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Warning: this approach does not take into account that `calendar` may be in the past. That will be the case for most of the day. You need to check to see if `calendar` is in the past, and if so, `add()` a day to it.